# Finding a website's "sitemap"- robots.txt / sitemap.xml leads to nothing

Tags: web-crawler, sitemap, google-sites

For some websites, for example [this](http://www.nakedcph.com) website has both `robots.txt` and `sitemap.xml` but they do not lead to any pages with products listed in an xml or json format. Are there any other ways to find out the sitemap with products listed on these sites? I've tried inspect element and SEO Quake with no luck so far.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sites aren't required to list their XML sitemaps publicly for search engines to crawl them. The site can either list it in the robot file or submit it to Google Search Console them the site to index.

Many sites will hide their full sitemaps (which appears to be the case for the domain you referenced) to prevent people from scrapping the site.

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/183668?hl=en